# show material-ui components in external window

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to open an external window and display React components inside of it. My implementation follows this article - https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202

Here's a gif of the problem - https://streamable.com/unfom

GitHub repo that reproduces the problem - https://github.com/sh3nan1gans/material-ui-external-window

I learned that I needed to use a custom JSS insertion point for the children of my external window so that any material-ui components would insert their styles into the external document.head instead of the original document. The problem with this is that when the external window is closed the material-ui components aren't styled correctly and components that use portals (i.e., Menus) don't anchor correctly. It seems like I need to reset the insertion point once the external window is closed.

Comment: Found an example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/308nkoz2xp I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 1):

Was able to figure it out based on this example - https://codesandbox.io/s/308nkoz2xp

The piece that I was missing was passing a `new Map()` into the `sheetsManager` prop for the `StylesProvider`